# How to show last item visible in iron-list?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm creating chat page. And I'm updating message with iron-list. Everytime I pusshed message to `array` `iron-list` added into that template. Now I want last appended message visible in the bottom. Currently user have to scroll to bottom and see that message.

```
// Polymer
  properties: {
    messageItem: { type: Array, notify: true, value: function() { return []; } },
  },

# Html
<iron-list items="[[messageItem]]" as="item">
  <template>...</template>
</iron-list>
```

Push code:

```
this.push('messageItem', {name: 'bot', message: event.data});
```

What necessary steps should I take to achieve this ?

Comment: Try setting `scrollTop` to `scrollHeight`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40340474/6277151

Comment: @tony19 trying that compination.  I gave an `id="lists"` to `iron-list` and gave `this.$.lists.scrollTop = this.$.lists.scrollHeight;` but have no luck

Comment: Worked fine for me. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `<iron-list>.scrollTop` to its `scrollHeight` after adding an item to the list and allowing it to render. You could use `Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender()` for that purpose:

```
// template
<iron-list id="list">...</iron-list>

// script
_addItem: function() {
  this.push('items', ...);
  Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, () => {
    this.$.list.scrollTop = this.$.list.scrollHeight;
  });
}
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      items: {
        type: Array,
        value: () => [0,1,2]
      }
    },
    _addItem: function() {
      this.push('items', this.items.length);
      this._scrollToBottom();
    },
    _scrollToBottom: function() {
      Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, () => {
        this.$.list.scrollTop = this.$.list.scrollHeight;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-list/iron-list.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        iron-list {
          border: solid 1px red;
          height: 100px;
        }
      </style>
      <button on-tap="_addItem">Add item</button>
      <iron-list id="list" items="[[items]]">
        <template>
          <div>[[item]]</div>
        </template>
      </iron-list>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JbWRmb?editors=1010)

Comment: cool.. givmme sec.. can you tell me what's wrong with this my actual code ? https://bitbucket.org/snippets/rajasimon/77n4y

Comment: @RobC Try giving `iron-list` a height.

Comment: @tony19 Hi did you noticed It's not actually scrolling the last element added into that list. Instead it showing previously added one. Why is that behaviour? How do we solve this one? Also I raised a question in https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/issues/357 Let me know what you thinking.

Comment: @RajaSimon It's because the list hasn't rendered yet. I've fixed the codepen, and I'm working on updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use iron-list, but from what I can figure, messageItem is an array of objects, so you can sort its elements by the value of one of the objects' attributes, for example index. I can see in their documentation that they have an index attribute you can add. Which means, you can sort the object array descending using index, so do something like:

```
messageItem.sort(function(index1, index2){return index1-index2});
```

where

```
index1 = messageItem[i].index; and index2 = messageItem[i-1].index;
```

That's my best idea :)

Comment: Okay that will get the index. Can you go to iron-list https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list#method-scrollToItem and any helps ?

Comment: Ok, so I see that actually iron-list shows a few visible items at once. So I see they have in their API lastVisibleIndex, maybe you can use that to set the Index dynamically. Then, depending on how many items you want to show in one view, create a while loop inside which to set the sort descending function.